# Selecting newest cert in a folder with a given subject name

Tags: linux, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

I'm looking at rotating certs on a Azure CRP linux VM, or a VMSS pool. The easiest way(installed by CRP from keyvault) to deploy them throws all the certs in a single folder (/var/lib/waagent) named {thumbprint}.prv for the key and {thumbprint}.crt for the cert. When I want to add a new cert I can kick off a command that will add the new cert in the same folder. 
 
 I'm currently looking at having a job watching the folder and looking to see if a subject name has a new cert and when it does cycling processes that depend on the subject name pointing them to the new cert. I know I can use openssl with a command like: 
 sudo openssl x509 -inform PEM -in /var/lib/waagent/{thumbprint}.pem  -subject -enddate -noout 
 To get the subject name and expiration date. Then I would have to track for each subject name returned which cert has the farthest in the future expiration date.
 
My question is this feels like a lot of work for a pretty common use case, wanting to find the cert that will last the longest for a given subject name. How is this handled on most linux servers? Is there a better way to find this out then to just have a bash script I run every t number of seconds that says we now have a new cert for subject names x y z so restart processes a b c only configure them to use the new certs j k l?

Comment: I've ended up deciding to be more deliberate in updating my certs/ needing to redeploy me service to update the cert. I've made my cert update logic orthogonal to the rest of my service so they should be fairly painless. This way I can explicitly select the correct cert. I also moved the cert download from CRP into a custom script at runtime. For the boot loading I'm using the service prinicpal kubernetes is using to do networking etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way to find this out then to just have a bash script
>   I run every t number of seconds that says we now have a new cert for
>   subject names x y z so restart processes a b c only configure them to
>   use the new certs j k l?

As far as I know, the script is more flexible than using a existing tools. It seems that you are looking for a certificate management tool on Linux. My suggestion is writing your own script. BTW, there are several commercial solutions which allow Linux clients enroll the certificate against Windows Server based CA server.